# Assigning Category specific values as observations in a new column

Tags: python, for-loop, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I'm assigning value "x" to all observations in column 'Superkingdom_name' when category Unknown1 is selected in Class column.

```
df.loc[df['class'] == "Unknown1", 'Superkingdom_name'] = "x"
```

Similarly for assigning value Y to Unknown2, I do it like this

```
df.loc[df['class'] == "Unknown2", 'Superkingdom_name'] = "y"
```

Question: Can we do this for multiple categories . But not manually. Can we loop it ? Instead of doing for each category as below :

```
df.loc[df['class'] == "Unknown1", 'Superkingdom_name'] = "x"
df.loc[df['class'] == "Unknown2", 'Superkingdom_name'] = "y"
df.loc[df['class'] == "Unknown2", 'Superkingdom_name'] = "z"
```

I could make a list of categories in "Class" column and make it an iterable like

```
df["class"].unique().tolist()
```

---> ["Unknown1","Unknown2","Unknown3"]

But I do not get how to assign values to the "Superkingdom_name" in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace().

```
df['Superkingdom_name']= df['class'].replace(['Unknown1','Unknown2','Unknown3'],['x','y','z'])
```

Comment: Thanks ! Could you give the structure of the for loop ?

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. See update.